# Adjusting space when using the "lettre" class

Tags: spacing, letters

I am quite new in writing letters with LaTeX, and I am wondering whether there is a way to adjust the space between the end of the sender's e-mail address and the subject of the letter (see picture below). I read the `lettre.cls` file but I was not able to find what I was looking for.

[image: The green arrow represents the space which length I need to modify]

Here is the code I have been using so far :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{lettre}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\NoRule}{\renewcommand*{\rule@length}{0}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{letter}
\name{}
\signature{SMITH John}

\address{SMITH John\\New-York\\90 California Street\\FRANCE}
\lieu{}
\telephone{+33 00 00 00 00 00}
\email{johnsmith@gmail.com}
\nofax
\nodate
\nobreak
\NoRule
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\concname{}


\conc{Subject : Speculative Job Application - NASA}

\opening{Dear Mr Doe,}

I am writing to express my interest in working with you.

\closing{Yours sincerely,}


\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your help,
Arnaud.

Answer (score 4):

The `lettre` class adds a rather big space after the address block and, additionally, twice the `\openingspace`, which is used between the subject and the opening line.

You can patch the `\letteropening` command in order to add a different spacing (also negative, as in the example below).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{lettre}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% The default value of \openingspace is 1cm.
% Instead of -\openingspace use the length you prefer
% for instance -0.5cm or whatever
\patchcmd{\letteropening}{2\openingspace}{-\openingspace}{}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\NoRule}{\renewcommand*{\rule@length}{0}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\begin{letter}
\name{}
\signature{SMITH John}

\address{SMITH John\\New-York\\90 California Street\\FRANCE}
\lieu{}
\telephone{+33 00 00 00 00 00}
\email{johnsmith@gmail.com}
\nofax
\nodate
\nobreak
\NoRule
\pagestyle{empty}
\def\concname{}


\conc{Subject: Speculative Job Application - NASA}

\opening{Dear Mr Doe,}

I am writing to express my interest in working with you.

\closing{Yours sincerely,}


\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in manipulating the letter content in a more comfortable way, I would suggest foregoing the `lettre` document class and roll your own letter using `article`. It's super-easy, since you don't have to specify so manu parameters that don't get placed where you want them... you just specify what you want, where you want it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{%
  hmargin=2in,% horizontal margin of 2in
  vmargin=1in % vertical margin of 1in
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indent
\pagestyle{empty}% No header/footer

\begin{document}

\hspace*{-1in}% Move address/reference 1in into left margin
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  SMITH John \\
  New-York \\
  90 California Street \\
  FRANCE \\[\medskipamount]
  Tél. +33 00 00 00 00 00 \\
  E-Mail: \texttt{johnsmith@gmail.com}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip% Space between address/reference and Subject

Subject: Speculative Job Application - NASA

\bigskip% Space between Subject and opening

Dear Mr Doe,

\medskip% Space between opening and letter content

I am writing to express my interest in working with you.

\bigskip% Space between letter content and closing

Yours sincerely,

\bigskip\bigskip% Space between closing and signature

\hfill% Signature is flush right
SMITH John% Signature

\end{document}
```

All of the above placements and lengths can be changed to suit your requirements. I find the code to be far more readable and therefore easy to manipulate/change.

Comment: Thank you, it works great. But, do you know how to adjust the length of the right vertical margin ?

Comment: @Nano: The [`geometry` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) allows for using `left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` key-values to specify the individual page geometry/margins. `vmargin=X` is equivalent to `top=X,bottom=X` and `hmargin=Y` is equivalent to `left=Y,right=Y`. So you can set these individually as you want.