# Lettre Class, how to supress this aweful blank space

Tags: margins, layout, lettre

I am currently writing a cover letter with the modified `lettre` package which is a modified version of the original letter, in order to correspond to french standards. Below a MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,loghighlight,french]{lettre}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Résponsable des ressources humaines}
\francais
\name{Gustave \textsc{Eiffel}}
\address{Tour Eiffel\\75000 Paris\\\textsc{France}}
\nofax
\telephone{+33 1 23 45 67 89}
\email{gustave.eiffel@gmail.com}
\lieu{Paris}
\date{\today}

%\tension{-20}% par défaut 2. p. 16 de l'aide.
\marge{0mm}% par défaut 15mm. p. 16 de l'aide.

\conc{Candidature au poste de météorologiste.}
\opening{Madame, Monsieur,}
\lipsum[1-3]

\closing{Dans l'espoir d'une réponse positive, je vous transmets Madame, Monsieur, mes sincères salutations.}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The text from my letter is a bit long so that the final letters output on two pages. Though, the presence of a huge gap between the adress fields and the letter's subject field.

After 2 compilations of the previous code, `tension` went to `2` to `-5` according to log file. But the second page is still filled by less than a third.

> "Class lettre Warning: Longueur de la derniere page : 119.60605pt<
>   130pt" :

[image: After 2 compilations of the previous code, tension went to 2 to -5 according to log file. The second page is filled by less than a third. "Class lettre Warning: Longueur de la derniere page : 119.60605pt< 130pt"]

In the [package documentation](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/lettre/lettre.pdf) page 16, it describes about the so called `tension` parameter that is responsible for shortening the blank gaps between elements in order to fit the letter on one page if the space taken on the second page is smaller than 1/3 of that second page. The `tension` value originally set to `2` is then adjusted after the first compilation of the `tex` file and then used for the second compilation. The user can manually set this value. Which I tried, resulting in aweful results.

Here with `\tension{-20}` :

[image: Here with <code>\tension{-20}</code>]

The `opening` and `closing` fields are completely crumbled within the text.

I have also tried to use the commands `\openingspace{}` and `\sigspace{}` and the solution as suggested [in this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257393/adjusting-space-when-using-the-lettre-class) which are supposed to help for the blank space height between the text core and signature/opening but without concluent results. The value indicating the space between the text **core** and signature (for the `\sigspace` command), completely ignoring the `\closing` field in between.

How to fix this letter once and for good?

I know this question has already been asked a lot either here or other forums but I did not find any convenient solution neither there or in the package manual.

Thanks for further help.

PS: note that it might be possible to fix this MWE letter as only the closing field is on the second page. Though, with the letter I want to write, few additional lines are located there but could still be fitted within the first page. Especially after receiving the compilation warning that less than a third of the second page is used: "119.60605pt< 130pt" for my letter. And slightly tuning the `tension` parameter for each letter I want to write is not a reliable technique I believe.

Comment: egreg's patch in the question you linked too works fine for me and is the correct solution. And you should put a complete address in the \begin{letter} argument, so that you can better judge the space.

Comment: Hi, thanks. The thing is that i don't have a complete adress to use. Only the title from the service I want to target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need a mix of two partial solutions:

1. use the patch given by egreg in his answer in your linked question, but we have to adjust the length `-\openingspace` you will see later:

   ```
   \usepackage{etoolbox} % <===============================================

   % The default value of \openingspace is 1cm.
   % Instead of -\openingspace use the length you prefer
   % for instance -0.5cm or whatever
   \patchcmd{\letteropening}{2\openingspace}{-\openingspace}{}{}
   ```
2. use `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` to get the signature removed from page two.

Please see that I simulated a real letter with an real recipient address with changing your used

```
%\begin{letter}{Résponsable des ressources humaines}
```

to

```
\begin{letter}{% <======================================================
  Pr.~E.T.~Phonom \\
  Departement Asprototographie \\
  Universite de Saint Zopium \\
  3945, Quai du General Gisant \\
  CH-6800 Motte-au-Rolla } % <==========================================
```

Then we need to change the length `-\openingspace` in the patch to better suited `-1cm`.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,loghighlight,french]{lettre}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{etoolbox} % <===============================================

% The default value of \openingspace is 1cm.
% Instead of -\openingspace use the length you prefer
% for instance -0.5cm or whatever
\patchcmd{\letteropening}{2\openingspace}{-1cm}{}{} % -\openingspace <================


\begin{document}

%\begin{letter}{Résponsable des ressources humaines}
\begin{letter}{% <======================================================
  Pr.~E.T.~Phonom \\
  Departement Asprototographie \\
  Universite de Saint Zopium \\
  3945, Quai du General Gisant \\
  CH-6800 Motte-au-Rolla } % <==========================================
\francais
\name{Gustave \textsc{Eiffel}}
\address{Tour Eiffel\\75000 Paris\\\textsc{France}}
\nofax
\telephone{+33 1 23 45 67 89}
\email{gustave.eiffel@gmail.com}
\lieu{Paris}
\date{\today}

%\tension{-9}% par défaut 2. p. 16 de l'aide.
\marge{0mm}% par défaut 15mm. p. 16 de l'aide.
\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip} % <====================================

\conc{Candidature au poste de météorologiste.}
\opening{Madame, Monsieur,}
\lipsum[1-3]

\closing{Dans l'espoir d'une réponse positive, je vous transmets Madame, 
  Monsieur, mes sincères salutations.}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I get the result:

[image: resulting letter]

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for the clear details.